# access denied to local intranet page for only 1 user

Tags: php, javascript, .net, authentication, access-denied

We have a PHP site hosted from an Apache server.

We have a .NET site hosted from a windows server.

Both are internal, and inside our domain.

When a user accesses the PHP site, it checks if your username has been sessioned.  If not, it does an ajax `GET` postback to the .NET "`GetUsername.aspx`" page.  The `GetUsername.aspx` page simply outputs `Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")`

The .NET site requries windows authentication to be enabled in IE.  All of our users use IE8.

In order for our PHP site to request data from the .NET site, a setting "Access data across domains" must be enabled... and it is.

In order for our .NET site to get your username, "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" must be nabled... and it is.

Both the .NET site, and the PHP site are intranet sites.  If you go to Internet Options -> Local Intranet -> Sites -> Advanced, both sites are in the list.

At this line: `xmlhttp.open("GET","http://intranet.MySite.vmv/IS/GetUsername.aspx",false);`

A javascript error occurrs with the message "Error: Access is denied."

If i type that same .NET page into the browser url... it loads just fine, and shows her username.

---

The confusing thing about all this, is that our policy updates (pushed out on every login) set all of these settings.  I've verified all the above settings are the same on my browser as they are on this users.  Both of us are within the same domain.

Any ideas of some other setting that could be causing this?

Thanks!

---

EDIT

here are the results from firebug... doesnt seem to be very helpful, just shows me what we already knew.

http://intranet.MyCompany.vmv/IS/GetUsername.aspx

```
401 Unauthorized
20ms    
login (line 103)
HeadersResponseHTML
Response Headers
Content-Length  1656
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Mon, 09 Apr 2012 16:15:33 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
WWW-Authenticate    Negotiate NTLM
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    intranet.MyCompany.vmv
Origin  http://192.168.1.2:10078
Referer http://192.168.1.2:10078/login
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
```

Comment: Can you use Fiddle, or FireBug to look at the actual network call made?

Comment: You are using Internet Explorer, right?

Comment: The error is because the browser isn't allowing cross domain access. Whatever setting you set to allow the cross domain access isn't working on that machine.

Comment: I'll see if I can get Firebug, and post an update with that.  We are all using IE8, correct.

Comment: Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @adam ignore my comment about FireBug, that's FireFox only. Fiddler, or Wireshark would work with IE. For future reference. Fiddler is best for network related issues in IE IMHO, it's like Wireshark, but it's easier to isolate to one application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... the issue appears to be with IE7.  Somehow this user's version was not upgraded with everyone else.  Once we upgraded her to IE8 it worked as expected.